Is compactness necessary?
I was thinking if the compactness is necessary here. I used the intermediate value theorem to prove that: Any compact interval (subspace of R) has the FP-property.  Does this means that compactness is necessary, or there is a counterexample for that.

Sorry, what is the "FP-property"?

it is the fixed point property

Yes, without compactness it's easy to construct self maps of intervals without fixed points.  If we consider unbounded intervals, then $F: R \to R$ given by $F(x) = x + 1$ is clearly fixed point free. If you want a bounded example, consider the $G: (0,1) \to (0,1)$ given by $G(x) = x^2$.
